# Data augmentation by adding noise in python regression model

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, regression, data-augmentation

I am building a regression model for a target variable which is heavy tailed. I want to augment data so that the model gets enough training samples in the region where it's a long tail. Accuracy of prediction for the rare data points is important.

I am currently augmenting data by adding noise to the training samples. After splitting into train and test, I do MinMaxScaler on all the features(X), but no scaling on the target variable(y).
Then, I add noise to both X and y with different mean and std since X is scaled to [0,1] but y isn't.
Here is the code for augmenting by adding noise

```py
    def add_noise(mean, std, df):
        noise = np.random.normal(mean, std, df.shape)
        df2= df.where(df <= 0.001 , df.add(abs(noise)))
        return df2
```

I invoke this using something like add_noise(0,0.005,X_train) and add_noise(0,1,y_train)
X_train is normalized/scaled so I can use a small std deviation. Now I have to decide what std deviation of y_train will cause only a small perturbation that corresponds to the perturbation to X_train.

Questions

1. How do I find the right mean and std for my y variable - keeping in mind that the model should see similar data distribution between the original dataset and the augmented one?
2. Any other suggestions on augmenting data for regression ?

Comment: This would probably get better answers if asked on [stats](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), as it is less of a programming and more of a statistics question.

Comment: I think Data Augmentation is not the right term for your problem. If you want to up-sample your dataset, you can follow this guide https://elitedatascience.com/imbalanced-classes